# yii search on active records

Tags: php, search, yii

I've this

```
$reviewModel=Review::model()->findAll();
```

Now I want to perform a search operation on $reviewModel,say I want to search if a user of id 1 has posted a review or not. so is there any function provided by yii.

> Note: I dont want to use
>   $reviewModel=Review::model()->findAll(array('condition'=>'')); As I
>   need all the reviews & then perform a search.

Comment: $reviewModel is an array of models. Or, what is the same in Yii, array of arrays. Use your preferred algorithm to find the values you need inside multidimensional array. Easy as that.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would recommend and is good design practice, also it will allow optimal performance from your database, + reduce the amount of queries. I would make your reviews have a relation with the user. As a user will post many reviews. so user HAS_MANY reviews. and Review and HAS_ONE user. so use that and create a foreign key to build the relationship.

So inside your user model (Relations) id have something like this:

```
'reviews' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Review', 'originator),
```

now inside your review model id have something like this:

```
'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'originator'),
```

Once you have done that all you would have to do is loop through all the users reviews. If its null, they don't have any reviews.

```
$user = User::model()->findbyPk(1);
```

and user->reviews would contain all the reviews for that user.

Comment: My question is totally different from your answer. I repeat I want all the reviews & then perform search operation on that

Answer (score 0):

Not that I am aware of (if I understand your question correctly). Yii provides various ways to ask for what you want from the DB but not from an array of active record models in memory.

If you want to do it this way then get the array of data as you already did and then use PHP to iterate through the array of models looking for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter through them manually. For example:

```
$reviewModel=Review::model()->findAll();

$matched = false;
foreach($reviewModel as $r)   //cycle through each review
{
    if($r->user == 1)         //check if user is desired
    {
        $matched = true;  //set matched as true
        break;        //stop searching, as we already found one
    }
}
```

if you want to search for multiple things, you can use an array for matched and then check that array.

```
$reviewModel=Review::model()->findAll();

$wanted = array(0=>false,3=>false,6=>false,8=>false);

foreach($reviewModel as $r) //cycle through each review
{
    if(isset($wanted[$r->user]) and !$wanted[$r->user]) //check if user is in wanted list and still false
    {
        $wanted[$r->user] == true; //set appropiate user to true
    }
}
```